# How do sort Entries of the Map<Type,List<String>> by Value and store into a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, comparable, collectors

I have the following `Item` class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public static class Item {
    public enum Type { Meat, Fish }

    private String name;
    private int price;
    private Type type;
}
```

And there's a `List` of items like shown below:

```
List<Item> menu = Arrays.asList(
    new Item("pork" 800, Item.Type.Meat), 
    new Item("beef" 700, Item.Type.Meat), 
    new Item("chicken", 200, Item.Type.meat), 
    new Item("prawns" 300, Item.Type.Fish),
    new Item("salmon", 450, Item.Type.Fish)
);
```

I need to group `Item` by `Type` and store into a map.

And then I need to sort *map entries* by *Value* (which in this case is a `List` of `String`s) in ascending order and store into a `LinkedHashMap`.

How do I sort a *map entries* based on a `List<String>` value?

*My code:*

```
// grouping items by type

Map<Item.Type, List<String>> map = menu.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Item:: getType,
        Collectors.mapping(Item::getName, Collectors.toList())
    ));

// a LinkedHashMap to store sorted entries

Map<Item.Type, List<String>> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

// attempting to sort map entries by value and put them
//  into the resulting map

map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<Item.Type, List<String>> comparingByValue())
    .forEachOrdered(e -> hmap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

But I'm getting a compilation error:

```
Type parameter 'java.util.List' is not within its bound;
should extend 'java.lang.Comparable<? super java.util.List>'
```

I think the reason is because I have a list of String in a map which I want to sort.

When I have just a `String` as a *value* (Not `List<String>`). The code works perfectly well.

Comment: I have  already grouped the Dish by the dish type. But I want to sort the names in ascending order

Comment: Can you explain this phrase *`"supposed to sort the values in ascending order"`*? Value - is not a single object, but a list of strings. `List` doesn't implements comparable. Do you want it to be compared as a single string?

Answer (score 1):

None of the Collections implement `Comparable` interface. There's no point in it, because they are containers of data, if you need to sort the data you're sorting it within the collection that is capable of maintaining the order. When you need to sort collections - that's a weird task.

I said weird because collections like `List` have no knowledge of how to compare their elements, meaning it's not mandatory for the elements to be comparable, and you can't provide a comparator while instantiating a list. As a consequence of this, it's not possible to establish the natural order for a `List`, in other words a list doesn't "know" how it can be compared with another list.

You need to define a *custom* `Comparator` for that purpose.

> When I have just a `String` as a value (Not `List<String>`). The code works perfectly well.

Assuming that you want your lists of string to be compared as if each of them is single is a single string (let's call it *comparison key*), then it would be wise to generate such strings in advance and associate every `Type` of item with a *comparison key* (if you have in mind different comparison strategy - then tweak the code accordingly).

*Comparison keys* can be generated right on the spot (in the stream), but it would lead to recreating the same strings multiple times. In this case it's not a big issue since `Item.Type` is an *enum* therefore the number of string comparison keys that correspond to each *enum-constant* is limited, but it wouldn't hurt to have them ready to use in advance.

```
List<Item> menu = Arrays.asList(
    new Item("pork", 800, Item.Type.Meat),
    new Item("beef", 700, Item.Type.Meat),
    new Item("chicken", 200, Item.Type.Meat),
    new Item("prawns", 300, Item.Type.Fish),
    new Item("salmon", 450, Item.Type.Fish)
);
    
Map<Item.Type, List<String>> itemNamesByType = menu.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Item:: getType,
        Collectors.mapping(Item::getName, Collectors.toList())
    ));

// generating Comparison Keys for every Type

Map<Item.Type, String> comparisonKeyByType = itemNamesByType.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        entry -> String.join("", entry.getValue())
    ));
    
Map<Item.Type, List<String>> itemNamesByTypeSorted = itemNamesByType.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(
        Comparator.comparing(comparisonKeyByType::get)
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,   // keyMapper
        Map.Entry::getValue, // valueMapper
        (left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError("duplicates not expected"); }, // since the source is an entry set - there shouldn't be duplicate keys (but we need to provide this argument in order to be able to use version of toMap() which allows to provide a mapFactory
        LinkedHashMap::new   // mapFactory
    ));
    
itemNamesByTypeSorted.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
Meat -> [pork, beef, chicken]
Fish -> [prawns, salmon]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement available method of list

- Compare Strings

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("d");
        values.add("a");
        values.add("g");

        hmap.put("1", values);
        hmap.put("2", values); 

        System.out.println(hmap); // --> {1=[d, a, g], 2=[d, a, g]}

        for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry: hmap.entrySet()){
            entry.getValue().sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        }
        System.out.println(hmap); // --> {1=[a, d, g], 2=[a, d, g]}
    }
```

- Compare by attribute list object

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List menu = Arrays.asList(
                new Dish("pork", 800, "Meat"),
                new Dish("beef", 700, "Meat"),
                new Dish("chicken", 200, "Meat"),
                new Dish("prawns", 300, "Fish"),
                new Dish("salmon", 450, "Fish"));

        Map<String, List<Dish>> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        hmap.put("1", menu);
        hmap.put("2", menu);

        System.out.println(hmap); // --> {1=[Dish{name='pork', price=800, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='beef', price=700, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='chicken', price=200, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='prawns', price=300, type='Fish'}, Dish{name='salmon', price=450, type='Fish'}], 2=[Dish{name='pork', price=800, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='beef', price=700, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='chicken', price=200, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='prawns', price=300, type='Fish'}, Dish{name='salmon', price=450, type='Fish'}]}

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Dish>> entry : hmap.entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().sort(Comparator.comparing(Dish::getName));
        }
        System.out.println(hmap); // --> {1=[Dish{name='beef', price=700, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='chicken', price=200, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='pork', price=800, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='prawns', price=300, type='Fish'}, Dish{name='salmon', price=450, type='Fish'}], 2=[Dish{name='beef', price=700, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='chicken', price=200, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='pork', price=800, type='Meat'}, Dish{name='prawns', price=300, type='Fish'}, Dish{name='salmon', price=450, type='Fish'}]}

    }
```

Comment: You rarely would have a data class implement Comparator of itself. Comparable, yes, since it makes sense for a class default to sort by its "natural" order but Comparator, rarely, and I can't think of a need to do this other than to confuse. What's more, why do you even do this when you're not even using this comparator but rather the Comparator class's lambda comparator.

Comment: sorry and many thanks, just my confuse @HovercraftFullOfEels